# Rasterio Source shape is inconsistent with given indexes 1

Tags: python, geotiff, rasterio

I need to save out a 3 band geotiff to file. I am currently using rasterio and when I go to write out the 3 band imagery I get the error `Source shape (1, 3445, 4703, 4) is inconsistent with given indexes 1`.

My final goal is to be able to perform some analysis on an image and write this out to file.

I have already tried `reshape_as_raster` and `reshape_as_image`. I have tried a few other combinations as well as .transpose(arr, (0,1,2))

https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/image_processing.html#imageorder

```
with rio.open(r"C:\Users\name\Documents\project\name.tif") as src:
naip_data = src.read()
naip_meta = src.profile

image = reshape_as_raster(naip_data)

with rio.open('C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\UAV_test_save\\filename.tif',     'w',**naip_meta) as dst:
        dst.write(image, 3)
```

I am expecting to have a geotiff saved in the file. instead I get:

> ValueError rasterio_io.pyx in rasterio._io.DatasetWriterBase.write()
>
> ValueError: Source shape (1, 3445, 4, 4703) is inconsistent with given
>   indexes 1

Comment: I cant find anyone with this issue, Any help out there?

Answer (score 8):

I have had the same issue. I solved it by removing the 'indexes' argument.

so instead of:

```
dst.write(image,indexes=3)
```

use this:

```
dst.write(image)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to solve the issue with the opposite approach (I added `, indexes = 1` to `dst.write`)

Answer (score 2):

Source metadata contains field `count` and it is equal to 1. You need to update that value to the desired number of output bands.

```
source_meta.update({
    "count": 3
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a 4 band raster that you are trying to write.

rio is reading (1, 3445, 4703, 4) as 1 band, 3445 rows, 4703 columns, and 4 of another dimension...I'm not a rio expert.

If you want to keep your 4 bands:

```
naip_data2 = np.moveaxis(naip_data.squeeze(),-1,0) # move axis with 4 entries to beginning and remove extra dimension

print(naip_data2.shape) # check new shape, should be (4,3445,4703)
print(naip_meta) # check that naip_data2.shape == (naip_meta['count'],naip_meta['height'],naip_meta['width'])

# if they are equal, naip_meta doesn't need to be updated, otherwise update it
with rio.open(fname,'w',**naip_meta) as dst:
    dst.write(naip_data2)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Good source](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/322385/writing-a-3-band-image-with-rasterio)

```
with rio.open(r"C:\Users\name\Documents\project\name.tif") as src:
naip_data = src.read()
naip_meta = src.profile

image = naip_data.reshape(3445,4703,4)

with rio.open('C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\UAV_test_save\\filename.tif',     
'w',**naip_meta) as dst:
    dst.write(image, [0,1,2],[2,1,0])
```